# Текст в качестве фона на заднем плане

Tags: css3, html5

Есть секция с заголовком на русском, а за ним едва заметно, как бы фоном, этот заголовок дублируется на английском. Пример на картинке:
[image: Пример макета с большим заголовком на заднем плане]

Основной заголовок "Обратная связь" и за ним едва заметно "CONTACTS", но еще таким образом, что слово как бы вылезает за рамки (темная область на фото - это граница макета), уходит за границу видимой области сайта.
Что сделал я:
Обернул заголовок в div и спозиционировал его относительно, а внутрь этого дива добавил другой div и уже в него положил CONTACTS, а сам div спозиционировал абсолютно.
Часть кода разметки:

```
<div class="section-title">
    <h2>Обратная связь</h2>
    <div class="bckgrnd-title">CONTACTS</div>
</div>
```

Часть кода стилей для фонового заголовка:

```
    .section-title {
    position: relative;
}

.bckgrnd-title {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -20;

    top: -90px;
    padding-left: 360px;

    font-size: 300px;
    letter-spacing: 45px;
    color: rgba(175, 174, 195, 0.05);
    font-family: "Proxima Nova Bold";
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Визуально, получилось что-то похожее, но проблема в том, что этот div создает горизонтальную прокрутку, чего быть не должно. Также не совсем понятно, как "обрезать" текст, чтобы был эффект, как на картинке выше.
Проще говоря - оно не работает.
Уважаемое сообщество, есть ли еще варианты реализации подобного?

Comment: Overflow hidden

Comment: @eri Способ работает, но не полностью. Если классу .section-title задать overflow: hidden;, то фоновый заголовок обрезается по краю контента, но в то же время он ужимается в полоску, равной ширине обычного h2. Соответственно, указание фиксированной высоты родительской секции сдвигает вниз весь остальной контент. Как побороть эту проблему? Или есть более изящные способы для подобной стилизации?

Comment: Оберни в див width 100%

Comment: @eri все пытался понять, о каком div'е идет речь и зачем там width 100%. Был бы признателен, если подскажете чуть подробнее